# Перенаправление на тестовую БД с помощью Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Здравствуйте, есть обычное CRUD приложение с использованием hibernate, без spring, в качестве сборщика gradle, для тестов использую testng, подскажите пожалуйста, как сконфигурировать gradle так, чтобы во время теста он перенаправлял на тестовую базу данных, если можно пример, спасибо.

Comment: Насчёт Gradle точно не знаю, но я бы использовал Git: вынести строку подключения в отдельный конфигурационный файл и сделать две ветки, отличающихся только в этом файле (и не мерджить его, конечно). И соответственно, переходить на тестовую ветку, когда это нужно.

Comment: @ЯниславКорнев, держать в гите информацию о подключении к БД - не самая хорошая идея. Больно становится в самый неожиданный момент.

Comment: К сожалению в данном случае без Git.

Comment: @soon, не затруднит вас подсказать, как это сделать, если вы знаете?

Comment: @soon почему же? Не вижу ничего плохого (конечно, если репозиторий не публичный), постоянно использую такой метод при тестировании на локальном сервере/с локальной БД.

Comment: @PolkovnikJ, не уверен, что это нужно решать на уровне gradle. Каким образом у вас сейчас определяется подключение к БД? Если бы вы использовали Spring, то все решалось бы дополнительной аннотацией для класса тестов с указанием нужного файла конфигурации. Здесь же, как мне кажется, стоит идти по аналогичному пути.

Comment: @ЯниславКорнев, меня всегда напрягает это уточнение: "конечно, если репозиторий не публичный". За последний год я лично слышал ее 2 раза, и оба раза репозитории, таки, становились публичными (не совсем открытыми, но приходилось расшаривать для других работников). Проще с самого начала настроить конфиг и уже не заморачиваться по этому поводу.

Comment: @ЯниславКорнев Да и каждый раз перед тестом переходить на нужную ветку - замороченно же. Еще и сливать их постоянно.

Comment: @soon подключение к БД определяется в конфигурационном xml файле hibernate.

Comment: @soon это делается по-другому. Весь код пишется в тестовой ветке, где в конфиге тестовые данные. Когда же после этапа разработки и тестирования нужно сделать очередной релиз, то только тогда производится слияние (кроме файла конфига), и из релизной ветке производится деплой (если же настроен нужный инструментарий, то автоматически). Ибо, я думаю, вы согласитесь, что писать код напрямую в релизную ветку работающего проекта - не самая лучшая практика.

Comment: @PolkovnikJ, в этом случае вы можете поискать аналоги [ContextConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html). Просто подсовываете ему нужную xml конфигурацию.

Comment: @ЯниславКорнев, Соглашусь, что данный подход имеет место быть, но что если у вас локально есть тестовая БД, и на сервере при каждом пуше прогоняются тесты на своей БД. В этом случае вы просто не коммитите изменения в файле подключения? Кроме того, если ваше приложение поставляется нескольким клиентам, то конфигурации у них, с большой долей вероятности, будут различаться (если, конечно, все это не обернуто в какой-нибудь красивый контейнер). В общем, хранение паролей в гите - не тот путь, которым стоит идти, на мой взгляд. Подсовывание нужной конфигурации при запуске ничуть не сложнее.